# "tag" and "tags" are not synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Okay, the meta tag [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) should either be removed, because 0 questions use it, or be turned into a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), because that just makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Tags with no questions get deleted automatically at midnight. [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) did have a question until [9 hours ago](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/850/revisions), so it's still around, but it'll be gone tonight